# Hippo CMS 10, interface HstSiteMapItemHandler

Tags: hippocms

In Hippo CMS 10, there is a interface called HstSiteMapItemHandler two methods are now not using any more in Hippo 10.

```
public interface HstSiteMapItemHandler {
    void init(ServletContext var1, SiteMapItemHandlerConfiguration var2) throws HstSiteMapItemHandlerException;

    ResolvedSiteMapItem process(ResolvedSiteMapItem var1, HttpServletRequest var2, HttpServletResponse var3) throws HstSiteMapItemHandlerException;

    void destroy() throws HstSiteMapItemHandlerException;
}
```

Before Hippo 10 it was,

```
public interface HstSiteMapItemHandler {
    void init(ServletContext var1, SiteMapItemHandlerConfiguration var2) throws HstSiteMapItemHandlerException;

    ResolvedSiteMapItem process(ResolvedSiteMapItem var1, HttpServletRequest var2, HttpServletResponse var3) throws HstSiteMapItemHandlerException;

    /** @deprecated */
    @Deprecated
    SiteMapItemHandlerConfiguration getSiteMapItemHandlerConfiguration();

    /** @deprecated */
    @Deprecated
    ServletContext getServletContext();

    void destroy() throws HstSiteMapItemHandlerException;
}
```

I am just wondering of somebody knows what i should use for deprecated code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadoc in pre-10 explained what you should use instead. It mentioned that if you want in your own `HstSiteMapItemHandler` impl to get hold of the `SiteMapItemHandlerConfiguration` or `ServletContext`, you just store the parameters of the `#init` method as instance variables of your `HstSiteMapItemHandler` impl.

HTH,

Regards Ard